# How to download items in the manifest from PHP

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to download derivative files to view them offline in our local server.

I have already tried to get manifest endpoint. but i have no clue how to download those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are lucky, I just have one PHP sample that demonstrate how to download the derivative files. Check out at https://github.com/JohnOnSoftware/forge.php.downloadsvf , I hope it helps for you:)